# Use of "legend to name" in tikzpicture generates extra pdf pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend, tikz-pic

I use tikz for a graph and just want to put a legend outside of my plot and convert the picture into a single pdf to include this in my Tex document.

(Instead of input the tikz file to my Tex document.)

I have this mininmal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{2cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{5cm}
\begin{document}
\ref{named}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
xmajorgrids,
xlabel={x},
ymin=0,
ymax=9,
ylabel={y},
ymajorgrids,
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left, legend columns=1},
legend to name=named
]
\addplot [
color=red,
line width=1.0pt
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 1\\
1 2\\
2 3\\
3 4\\
4 1\\
5 6\\
};
\addlegendentry{example};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

(The legend actually appears centered.)

What I need is just one pdf page with the legend but what I get are three pages. How could this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I actually don't get the last empty page.)

You could put the legend in a `node` inside the `tikzpicture`, i.e. add

```
\node [above] at (current bounding box.north) {\ref{named}};
```

right after `\end{axis}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figureheight{2cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
xmajorgrids,
xlabel={x},
ymin=0,
ymax=9,
ylabel={y},
ymajorgrids,
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left, legend columns=1},
legend to name=named
]
\addplot [
color=red,
line width=1.0pt
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 1\\
1 2\\
2 3\\
3 4\\
4 1\\
5 6\\
};
\addlegendentry{example};
\end{axis}
\node [above] at (current bounding box.north) {\ref{named}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```